# Update values in pandas df column by adding fixed variable to preceding value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I am trying to project out the value in one column by adding a fixed value. Essentially, it would be like a sheet in Excel where there would be a value in cell a1, a fixed value in cell b1, and a2 would be =sum(a1+$b$1) and dragging the cells down. It seems like that would be straightforward in pandas, perhaps involving .cumsum, but I haven't found a way to get my desired result.

Here is my data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date_column" : ["2020-08-16", "2020-08-17", "2020-08-18", "2020-08-19", "2020-08-20" , "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-23", "2020-08-24", "2020-08-25" ] , 
"purchases" : [23,'','','','','','','','','']})

df
date_column    purchases
0   2020-08-16     23
1   2020-08-17    
2   2020-08-18    
3   2020-08-19    
4   2020-08-20    
5   2020-08-21    
6   2020-08-22    
7   2020-08-23    
8   2020-08-24    
9   2020-08-25
```

Separately, I have calculated a variable called avg_increase for the preceding two weeks.

```
avg_increase
2.5000000
```

I want to add the avg_increase value to the initial value in the purchases column, and then add the avg_increase to that value, and so on. The desired output is:

```
date_column    purchases
0   2020-08-16     23
1   2020-08-17    25.5
2   2020-08-18    28
3   2020-08-19    30.5
4   2020-08-20    33
5   2020-08-21    35.5
6   2020-08-22    38
7   2020-08-23    40.5
8   2020-08-24    43
9   2020-08-25    45.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution assuming ordered index `0..N`:

```
df.purchases = df.loc[0,"purchases"]+df.index.values*2.5
```

result:

```
  date_column  purchases
0  2020-08-16       23.0
1  2020-08-17       25.5
2  2020-08-18       28.0
3  2020-08-19       30.5
4  2020-08-20       33.0
5  2020-08-21       35.5
6  2020-08-22       38.0
7  2020-08-23       40.5
8  2020-08-24       43.0
9  2020-08-25       45.5
```

Simply get first value of `purchases` and add index values multiplied by 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `ffill` with `cumsum` create the increase steps

```
df.purchases = df.purchases.where(df.purchases!='').ffill()+df.purchases.eq('').cumsum()*2.5
Out[190]: 
0    23.0
1    25.5
2    28.0
3    30.5
4    33.0
5    35.5
6    38.0
7    40.5
8    43.0
9    45.5
Name: purchases, dtype: float64
```